# How do I evaluate this log expression:$\log_8{8^{17}}$?

Tags: logarithms

Evaluate the expression

$\log_8{8^{17}}$

I ended up getting $8^x = 8^{17}$.

I'm guessing I find x, but that's a huge number, and I feel like I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: By inspection, what should $x$ be?

Comment: The log of a number means, what power do you have to raise the base by to get the thing that you are taking the logarithm of ... i.e. in your case, what power do you raise $8$ by to get $8^{17}$ ...

Answer (score 1):

For any $0<a \neq 1$, $b>0$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, we had that:

$$
\textrm{log}_{a}b^{r} = r \cdot \textrm{log}_{a}b
$$

In your example:

$$
\textrm{log}_{8}8^{17}=17 \cdot \textrm{log}_{8}8
$$

Como $\textrm{log}_{b}b=1 \; \Rightarrow \textrm{log}_{8}8=1$

And because of that we had:

$$
\textrm{log}_{8}8^{17}=17 \cdot \textrm{log}_{8}8=17 \cdot 1 = 17
$$

Answer (score 0):

$x=\log_8{8^{17}}=\frac{\log{8^{17}}}{\log{8}}=17\frac{\log{8}}{\log{8}}=17$.

You use the property for changing the base of the logarithm at the second equality.